# Subquery returned more than 1 value error when using SELECT TOP

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm receving the following error when executing the code below and not sure why I'm getting it because I'm using a SELECT TOP. I cannot see any output when I execute the query but can anyone see what's wrong with it?

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT f.FixtureID,
        ht.FinalTeamWeight - at.FinalTeamWeight AS TeamScore
    FROM dbo.Fixture f

...

)


UPDATE f 
SET f.HomeScore = s.HomeScore,
    f.AwayScore = s.AwayScore
FROM dbo.Fixture f
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT FixtureID,
    TeamScore,
    (
        SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN c.TeamScore BETWEEN HomeWeighting AND AwayWeighting AND HomeScore > AwayScore AND s.ScoreDifference = sr.ScoreDifference
                THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore > AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = 1 ORDER BY NEWID())     
        END AS ScoreID
        FROM dbo.Score s
        LEFT JOIN ScoreReference sr
        ON s.ScoreDifference = sr.ScoreDifference

    ) AS ScoreID -- end select case

FROM cte c

 ) -- end inner join

 AS ScoreResult
    ON f.FixtureID = ScoreResult.FixtureID
INNER JOIN Score s
    ON ScoreResult.ScoreID = s.ScoreID
INNER JOIN ScoreReference sr
    ON s.ScoreDifference = sr.ScoreDifference
```

TABLES:
SCORE_REFERENCE

[image]

SCORE:

[image]

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your `SELECT CASE` gives more than one result.

Comment: You have multiple subqueries here, more than one of which is being used in a position where it should return a single value. Just because you use `TOP 1` in *one* of them, why are you discounting the others as being the source of this message?

Comment: The issue certainly comes from `TeamScore,(SELECT <-`

Comment: Oh, and contrary to the currently posted answers, don't just *blindly* apply `TOP 1` to other subqueries. If you genuinely believed that the subquery should have been returning one row only, first seek to *understand* your data and work out *why* it was in fact returning more than a single row. Then you won't necessarily apply the "pick a random row" strategy that the answers suggest.

Comment: Did you write the query, or someone else? General tip: do joins instead of sub-queries if you're not sure just one row is returned.

Comment: slighty off topic, but did you realise the the (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score.. )  will evaluate a random value just once (per execution) and apply that single selected random value for ScoreID to all results.  May be this is correct for you design but thought I mention it in case is wasn't!

Comment: @Phil B yeah I knew it will always execute a random value for Score ID. I wrote the query but I wanted to change it from hard code values to lookup table but didn't think that because I included an extra seelct, that I need to reference a column up there, hence the missing TOP 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add TOP(1) here...

```
SELECT TOP(1)
        CASE 
            WHEN c.TeamScore BETWEEN HomeWeighting AND AwayWeighting AND HomeScore > AwayScore AND s.ScoreDifference = sr.ScoreDifference
                THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore > AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = 1 ORDER BY NEWID())     
        END AS ScoreID
        FROM dbo.Score s
        LEFT JOIN ScoreReference sr
        ON s.ScoreDifference = sr.ScoreDifference
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the onw with TOP but the one which contains it. Add a TOP 1 on that one also